# Can't escape quote character in @Query in Spring Boot app for Cassandra

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

These queries don't run in the repository of the Cassandra SpringBoot App:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE viewer_id='?0'")
    Iterable<Activity> findByApp_Id(String appId);

@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE viewer_id=''?0''")
    Iterable<Activity> findByApp_Id(String appId);

@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE viewer_id='''?0'''")
    Iterable<Activity> findByApp_Id(String appId);

@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE viewer_id=\'?0\'")
    Iterable<Activity> findByApp_Id(String appId);
```

BUT,

this does:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE viewer_id='v1'")
    Iterable<Activity> findByApp_Id(String appId);
```

It seems that spring doesn't escape the query properly. How can I solve this ?

Comment: That should be fixed with Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 (RC1), see https://spring.io/blog/2016/12/23/spring-data-release-train-ingalls-rc1-released. You don't need escaping anymore.

Comment: It gives me this error on using 1.5 


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.cassandraMapping
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace? Just an excerpt won't help.

Comment: There's no stack trace for the option : '?0', there's no row returned though there exists one. Here's the stack trace for option: ''?0'' 

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
line 1:41 missing EOF at 'null' (...*FROM activities2 WHERE actor_id=''[null]...); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:41 missing EOF at 'null' (...*FROM activities2 WHERE actor_id=''[null]...)

Comment: Invalid null value in condition for column actor_id; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value in condition for column actor_id 

This is the stack trace for the option :
@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE actor_id=?0")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377271/how-to-query-cassandra-using-cassandrarepository-with-spring-data-cassandra-and ANy thoughts @mp911de