# How to Query Cassandra using CassandraRepository with Spring Data Cassandra and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Table in my Cassandra Cluster built using these commands:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS activitylogs WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activitylogs.activities2 (
    activity_id timeuuid,
    actor_id text,
    app_id text,
    item_id text,
    viewer_id text,
    activity_type int,
    ts timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (actor_id, activity_id, app_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activity_id DESC, app_id ASC);
```

This is what my Repository in Spring Project looks like:

```
public interface ActivityRepository extends CassandraRepository<Activity> {

@Query("SELECT actor_id FROM activities2 WHERE actor_id='actorA'")
Iterable<Activity> findByActor_Id(String actor_Id);
}
```

Now, when I access the endpoint associated with this query retriever , I get the following error:

```
Invalid null value in condition for column actor_id
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
```

However, when I run the equivalent CQL command in CQLSHell I get the exact row I was looking for...

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Any thoughts ? - @mp911de

Comment: Do you mind sharing which version of Spring Data and Datastax Driver you are using? Do you have github repo? Will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in writing the controller for the SpringBoot app.

The proper controller is thus:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activity/{actor_id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Activity> activity1(**@PathVariable("actor_id")** String actor_id) {
        List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
        activityRepository.findByActor_Id(actor_id).forEach(e->activities.add(e));
        return activities;
    }
```

Earlier implementation (at the time of writing the question) did not have @PathVariable annotation hence, controller wasn't passing any value to the repository interface function.